# Prove if $s<x$ and $t<z$, then $st<xz$.

Tags: inequality, induction

Assuming $s,t,x,z$ are natural numbers, if $s < x$ and $t < z$, then $st < xz$. Prove this.

Do I need induction? Please help.

I am very confused.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate a bit. Without any more context, the statement is false: consider $s,t=-2$ and $x,z=1$

Comment: but wouldn't that still make st < xz? -2<1??

Comment: This is not true. $-1<0$ and $0<1$, but you can’t conclude that $0<0$. You probably want to consider only positive numbers.

Comment: @qq2657 $st=4$ and $xz=1$

Comment: @qq2657 I think the strict inequalities will be weaker ones.

Comment: If $0< s$ and $0 < t$ you use the axiom $a < b$ and $0 < r$ then $ra < rb$ twice.  (The axiom can't be proven-- it's an axiom).  And if you don't know that $0 < s$ and $0< t$ then this isnt necessarily true.

Comment: @fleablood That may or may not be an axiom.  There are lots of different axiom systems.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't want to get bogged down.

Comment: assuming s,t,x,z are natural numbers

Answer (score 2):

This is false; a counterexample would be

$$1 < 2 \;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\; -2 < -1 \;\;\; \text{but} \;\;\; 1(-2) = -2 \not < -2 = 2(-1)$$

In general, though, unless you are limited to have $s,t,x,z \in \mathbb{Z}$, you wouldn't even try to use induction on this. Induction doesn't quite work with real numbers.